# Como desactivar Sábado y Domingo en table_calendar FLUTTER

Tags: android-studio, flutter, calendar

[image: Desactivar Sabado y Domingo]

[image: El código del TableCalendar]

Buenas Noches espero que esten bien,Necesito retirar de mi calendario los dias sabados y Domingos o a su vez desactivar estos dias. Porfavor Ayuda. Muchas Gracias de Antemano.

```
TableCalendar(
                locale: 'es_ES',
                startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                onDaySelected: (date1,events){
                },
                initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
                weekendDays: <int>[DateTime.saturday, DateTime.sunday],
                calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                  todayColor: Color(0xFF979797),
                  selectedColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  selectedStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'BalooMedium',
                    fontSize: (5.80 * size_config.imageSizeMultiplier),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                  centerHeaderTitle: true,
                  formatButtonVisible: false,
                ),
                calendarController: _controller,
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero cabe aclarar que hay que trabajar con los builders del Table Calendar y no con la versión mas sencilla
Esto se logra con enabledDayPredicate dentro  del TableCalendar y en tu caso:

```
return TableCalendar(
      enabledDayPredicate: (date) {
        return (date.weekday != DateTime.sunday && date.weekday != DateTime.saturday);
      },
```

Y luego se pueden sacar los días debajo del header poniendo en el CalendarBuilders lo siguiente:

```
builders: CalendarBuilders(
        dowWeekendBuilder: (context, date) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          );
        },
```

Hay que trabajar un poco mas para que quede prolijo según lo que necesites pero es un comienzo

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo con tu ayuda pude solucionarlo. Gracias de Verdad